Discord JSON + Google Forms⁠
Я создал гугл форму и подключил её по скрипту к дискорд каналу. Но когда я пытаюсь отправить слишком большой текст, то у меня разбивается текст на блоки. Как можно удалить это разделение и что бы текст можно было отправлять большой?
Прикладываю фотографию:
https://imgur.com/a/rvFNcvg
Сам скрипт:
const URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/";

var LEFT_COLOR = "16711680"; // 16711680;

var HEADER = "JSON";

var DESCRIPTION = "Some The Text";

var THUMBNAIL = "https://i.imgur.com/Ymuqmqn.jpeg";

const SEND_TIME = true;

var CONTENT = "<@&7283545455495>, <@&728355454545694>";

function onSubmit(e) {

const response = e.response.getItemResponses();

let items = [];

for (const responseAnswer of response) {

const question = responseAnswer.getItem().getTitle();

const answer = responseAnswer.getResponse();

let parts = []

try {

parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];

} catch (e) {

parts = answer;

}

if (!answer) {

continue;

}

for (const [index, part] of Object.entries(parts)) {

if (index == 0) {

items.push({

"name": question,

"value": part,

"inline": false

})

} else {

items.push({

"name": question.concat(" (удалит)"),

"value": part,

"inline": false

});

}

}

}

var TIME = "";

if (SEND_TIME) {

TIME = new Date().toISOString();

}

var options = {

"method": "post",

"headers": {

"Content-Type": "application/json",

},

"payload": JSON.stringify({

"content": CONTENT,

"embeds": [{

"title": HEADER,

"description": DESCRIPTION,

"color": LEFT_COLOR,

"fields": items,

"thumbnail": {

"url": THUMBNAIL

},  

"timestamp": TIME

}],

})

};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);

};


